# How to use the name of a const int property

Tags: c#, enums, constants

I have the following consts I use to check the database values f.e.:

```
public static class ConnectionConst
{
    public const int NotConnected = 0;
    public const int Connected = 1;
    public const int Unknown = 2;
    // ...
}
```

Now I don't want to show the integer values in the datagrid but the values of the const properties. F.e. 'Connected' instead of '1'.

Comment: What you want is an enum

Comment: You really want to show the string `NotConnected` in the UI with no space?

Comment: If you are using WPF and want to display `"Not Connected"` (note the space) or something similar you could create an `IValueConverter` for the binding with a big `switch` statement that converts each value to a corresponding string.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Ugh, that's not a great idea. Better to add attributes to the enum values like `[Display("Not Connected")]` for example.

Comment: @DavidG True, that would be the cleaner approach.

Comment: Thanks all. I now use an enum...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

why not using an enum:

```
public enum ConnectionConst
{
    NotConnected = 0,
    Connected = 1,
    Unknown = 2
}
```

You can have a variable of this type:

```
ConnectionConst connectionState = ConnectionConst.Unknown;
```

and in the `DataGridView` the value `"Unknown"` should appear

EDIT:

if you are already using C# 6 or higher you could also use [nameof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof) in your example with the static class:

```
string value = nameof(ConnectionConst.Unknown);
```

Comment: Or if not, just use `connectionState.ToString();`

Comment: Glad someone remembered `nameof` :)

Comment: @IanH. Well, nameof [isn't always such a great thing](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2Fr%2Fcsharp%2Fcomments%2F6pw5dy%2Fpuzzle_when_is_nameofnameof_a_valid_c_expression%2Fdksy7zh%2F&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNEPktKd70_UCsNv8ZLRh6aKGcytqQ)

Comment: @DavidG Totally, having an `enum` is surely the better way to go, but I'm glad that someone still acknowledges these little C# built-ins.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to display name with spaces like `Not Connected` instead of `NotConnected` you can try to use this:

```
public enum ConnectionConst
{
    [Description("Not Connected")]
    NotConnected = 0,
    [Description("Connected")]
    Connected = 1,
    [Description("Unknown")]
    Unknown = 2
}

public static string DisplayEnumName(Enum value)
{
    var name = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
    var attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])name.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

    if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0) {
        return attributes(0).Description;
    } else {
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then just use this:

```
var name = DisplayEnumName(ConnectionConst.NotConnected);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what XardasLord and DavidG suggested, I'd put that enum description getting code into an `IValueConverter`.

```
public class EnumDescriptionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return "";

        string stringRepresentation = value.ToString();
        Type T = value.GetType();
        if (!T.IsEnum) return stringRepresentation;

        MemberInfo[] enumMembers = T.GetMember(stringRepresentation);
        if (enumMembers.Length <= 0) return stringRepresentation;

        DescriptionAttribute[] memberAttributes = enumMembers[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false) as DescriptionAttribute[];
        if (memberAttributes == null) return stringRepresentation;
        if (memberAttributes.Length <= 0) return stringRepresentation;

        return memberAttributes[0].Description;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Or Binding.DoNothing, or throw an Exception, whichever you prefer
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

And use it in the Binding of your Column:

```xaml
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <local:EnumDescriptionConverter x:Key="DescriptionConverter"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=YourMemberNameHere, Converter={StaticResource DescriptionConverter}}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```